# How to get ID of specific tableviewcell on clicking of uiswitch present on it

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am facing an issue UITableViewCell.I have list of dynamic data generated using parse. Now user will check/uncheck that cell using UISwitch.I have to store that user action and send it to other viewController.

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: HotspotCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("htuiViewCell") as! HotspotCustomCell
        let singleHotspot = hotSpots[indexPath.row]
        cell.sendCell(singleHotspot.hotspotID, hotspotImg: singleHotspot.hotspotImage, hotspotLbl: singleHotspot.hotspottName)
        return cell
    }`

```
func sendCell(hotspotID : String ,hotspotImg : PFFile , hotspotLbl : String) {
    var tempImage:UIImage!
    hotspotImg.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let imageData = imageData {
                /*Setting up the veriable tempImage.*/
                tempImage = UIImage( data:imageData )
                self.hotspotImage.image = tempImage
                self.hotspotImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.hotspotImage.frame.size.width / 2
                self.hotspotImage.clipsToBounds = true
                self.hotspotLabel.text = hotspotLbl

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get which item in UITableViewCell is selected.
[image]

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called when you select  particular cell.

Comment: But i want to get particular cell data on uiSwitch event.

Comment: I have added an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 // Declare inside your Class file
 var customIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()


 //Add this inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath
 customIndexPath = indexPath
 println(customIndexPath)


 //Create an IBAction on switch
 @IBAction func switchOnOFF(sender: AnyObject) {

   println(customIndexPath)
   //Use the customIndexPath variable inside your Switch action
 }
```

Comment: Thanks karios. But this event will only get file if he will tab a tableviewcell. I want data when he tab to switch not on tableviewcell.

Comment: You can use tags for switch and create common IBAction for both switch. Depending on the tag value you can perform the respective action.

Comment: But i cannot store string value in tag .

Comment: For cell one use  switch tag as 1. Similar for cell two use switch tag as 2. In your action check tag is equal to 1 then action is preformed on cell one switch.